# Munkres wrote $(f^\sigma)^\tau=f^{\tau\circ\sigma}$ in "Analysis on Manifolds". But I proved $(f^\sigma)^\tau=f^{\sigma\circ\tau}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I am reading "Analysis on Manifolds" by James R. Munkres.

There is the following lemma in this book:

> Lemma 27.3.  Let $f$ be a $k$-tensor on $V$; let $\sigma, \tau \in S_k$.
>   (a) The transformation $f \to f^\sigma$ is a linear transformation of $\mathcal{L}^k(V)$ to $\mathcal{L}^k(V)$. It has the property that for all $\sigma, \tau$,
>   $$(f^\sigma)^\tau=f^{\tau\circ\sigma}.$$

But I "proved" $(f^\sigma)^\tau=f^{\sigma\circ\tau}$.
Please tell me my mistake in my proof?

> My wrong "proof":
>   $f^\sigma(v_1, \cdots, v_k) := f(v_{\sigma(1)}, \cdots, v_{\sigma(k)}) = f(w_1, \cdots, w_k)$, where $w_i := v_{\sigma(i)}$.
>   $f^\tau(w_1, \cdots, w_k) := f(w_{\tau(1)}, \cdots, w_{\tau(k)}) = f(v_{\sigma(\tau(1))}, \cdots, v_{\sigma(\tau(k))}) = f^{\sigma\circ\tau}(v_1, \cdots, v_k).$
>   So, $(f^\sigma)^\tau=f^{\sigma\circ\tau}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $w_i=v_{\sigma(i)}$, let's write
\begin{align}
f^{\sigma}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)&=f(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})=f(w_1,\ldots,w_k)\\
f^{\tau}(w_1,\ldots,w_k)&=f(w_{\tau(1)},\ldots,w_{\tau(k)})=f(v_{\sigma(\tau(1))},\ldots,v_{\sigma(\tau(k))})=f^{\sigma\circ\tau}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)
\end{align}
Your idea was to add $\tau$ as superscript at $f$ in the first line, as showed next:
$$\color{red}{(f^{\sigma})^{\tau}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)=f^{\tau}(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})}=f^{\tau}(w_1,\ldots,w_k)$$
and the red part is wrong! It must be $(f^{\tau})^{\sigma}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)=f^{\tau}(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Fakemistake.

Comment: It's better to think in the last step, to replace $f$ by $f^{\tau}$ in the first line.

Answer (score 5):

$(f^\sigma)^\tau(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$ is $f^\sigma(v_{\tau(1)},\ldots,v_{\tau(k)})$, not $f^\tau(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)})$.

If we put $g=f^\sigma$ and $u_i=v_{\tau(i)}$, we should have
\begin{aligned}
(f^\sigma)^\tau(v_1,\ldots,v_k)
&=g^\tau(v_1,\ldots,v_k)\\
&=g(v_{\tau(1)},\ldots,v_{\tau(k)})\\
&=\color{red}{f^\sigma(u_1,\ldots,u_k)}\\
&=f(u_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,u_{\sigma(k)})\\
&=f(v_{\tau(\sigma(1))},\ldots,v_{\tau(\sigma(k))})\\
&=f^{\tau\circ\sigma}(v_1,\ldots,v_k).
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you very much, user1551. Fakemistake answerd earlier than you, so I chose Fakemistake's answer. Thank you.